# I want to match rows in one table with rows in another table and each row should just be matched once

Tags: php, mysql

I want to match rows in one table with rows in another table and each row should just be matched once. I have constructed the below query which in all other respects works fine except that I am failing to tweak it further so that a row may only be selected once.

```
try{$results_pref_school1 = $db->query('SELECT mps.mps_client_ec_no, mcs.mcs_client_ec_no, mps.mps_school_id, mcs.mcs_school_id
                                          FROM match_pref_schools AS mps
                                          INNER JOIN match_current_schools AS mcs
                                          ON mps.mps_school_id = mcs.mcs_school_id
                                          AND mcs.mcs_id IN (SELECT MIN(mcs.mcs_id) 
                                                              FROM match_current_schools AS mcs 
                                                              GROUP BY mcs.mcs_school_id)
                                          ORDER BY mcs.mcs_id');
}catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Failed to retrieve matched preferred school';
        exit;

}
$matched_school = $results_pref_school1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

A var_dump of $matched_school produces:

```
Array
(

[1] => Array
    (
        [mps_client_ec_no] => REG5
        [mcs_client_ec_no] => GL98888
        [mps_school_id] => 6
        [mcs_school_id] => 6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [mps_client_ec_no] => TAS4752
        [mcs_client_ec_no] => ALF1252
        [mps_school_id] => 14
        [mcs_school_id] => 14
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [mps_client_ec_no] => MAP002
        [mcs_client_ec_no] => ALF1252
        [mps_school_id] => 14
        [mcs_school_id] => 14
    )

)
```

In the above result I wanted ALF1252 to be matched only once.

Answer (score 0):

@Parts  **Hope this is helpful for your query**

**in this i added index keys for remove "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) ",  and add one
   matched rows and your query performance now is best.**

QUERY:

```
SELECT mps.mps_client_ec_no,mps.mps_school_id, mcs.mcs_client_ec_no,  mcs.mcs_school_id 
                                          FROM match_pref_schools AS mps   INNER JOIN match_current_schools AS mcs
                                          ON mps.mps_school_id = mcs.mcs_school_id
                                          where mcs.mcs_id IN (SELECT MIN(mcs.mcs_id) 
                                                              FROM match_current_schools AS mcs 
                                                              GROUP BY mcs.mcs_school_id)
                                          ORDER BY mcs.mcs_id
```

Index :

> ```
> KEY `mcs-key` (`mcs_school_id`,`mcs_id`,`mcs_client_ec_no` )
>
> KEY `mps-key` (`mps_school_id`,`mps_client_ec_no`)
> ```
>
> INSERT INTO match_current_schools
>       (`mcs_id`, `mcs_client_ec_no`, `mcs_school_id`, `mcs_distr_id`, `mcs_province_id`, `mcs_client_level_taught`, `mcs_sub1_id`,
>   `mcs_sub2_id`) VALUES (6, 'XYZ', 1, 27, 3, 'HIGH SCHOOL - A LEVEL', 1,
>   9);

check here :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4103d/2

Comment: @kuldeed. I altered my tables and query as advised but I am still getting the same results. Check here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8098cb/1

Comment: @Parts  end of reslt wht you want  output? please tell me

Comment: I just want each row in match_current_schools to be fetched once. For example if ALF1252 is matched with MAP002 it was not supposed to be matched with TAS4752 again.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8098cb/1